# could not save the list changes to the server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

while creating custom form it shows error. [Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7dvR.png)

I have done with clear cache and web browser history clean.

Comment: Hi Priya. You should add some more context to your question so readers are able to get an idea of what you're trying to do. Which version of SharePoint are you using? Is it an on-premises (server) installation, or are you using the cloud version SharePoint Online? Can you provide screenshots or code from Designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently have the same problem on all lists, so most answers to this question aren't applicable.

I think it is a problem on MS side at this point to be honest.

Comment: I would have, but I lack the reputation

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has an advisory on the Microsoft 365 Admin Center.

SP186130 Can't Create Forms. Scope:  Any user attempting to create new forms on SharePoint Online lists via SharePoint Designer is affected.

Comment: I cannot find any record of the advisory you mentioned. Looks like the MS history only goes back 30 days. :(

I just started getting this last week. Was having issues with some lists and when I went to  add a new form with SharePoint Designer 2013, I found I couldn't (same error).